# ASP.NET with MS Chart disable the vertical line

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, data-visualization, mschart

I have a graph created with MS Chart like the following picture. As you can see the vertical lines are messed up with value of the top of each bar.

[alt text http://img46.imageshack.us/img46/3720/chartimgaxd.png](http://img46.imageshack.us/img46/3720/chartimgaxd.png)

Here's the mark-up for the graph:

```
        <asp:Chart ID="chtNBAChampionships" runat="server">
   <Series>
      <asp:Series Name="Championships" YValueType="Int32"  ChartType="Column" ChartArea="MainChartArea" IsValueShownAsLabel="true">
         <Points>
            <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="Celtics" YValues="17" />
            <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="Lakers" YValues="15" />
            <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="Bulls" YValues="6" />
            <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="Spurs" YValues="4" />
            <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="76ers" YValues="3" />
            <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="Pistons" YValues="3" />
            <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="Warriors" YValues="3" />

         </Points>
      </asp:Series>
   </Series>
   <ChartAreas>
      <asp:ChartArea Name="MainChartArea">
      </asp:ChartArea>
   </ChartAreas>
</asp:Chart>
```

I don't want the display the vertical line because it's messed up with the value on top of the each bar. How can I disable the vertical line?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know the specific ASP syntax, but here is the VB.NET code that does the trick:

```
Dim gd As New System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Grid
gd.LineWidth = 0

myChart.ChartAreas("MainChartArea").AxisX.MajorGrid = gd
```

C# version if needed :

```
System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Grid gd = new System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Grid(); 
gd.LineWidth = 0; 

myChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid = gd;
```

As you can see, you can't just turn off the gridline, you have to set it's width to 0.  The MinorGrid can be hidden the same way.

Comment: This works, but Disabling the MajorGrid using the `Enabled` property is probably the best way to do it.

Comment: @arviman, at the time of posting, setting the Enabled property to false did not actually disable or turn off the gridline.  Can you confirm if this behavior has changed/been fixed in the intervening months?

Answer (score 14):

simple way:

```
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

This resolved the issue. Thanks.

Below is the c# code....

```
var gd = new System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Grid();
gd.LineWidth = 0;
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid = gd;
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way, put the following code in chart load event.

```
protected void Chart1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
    Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could work from source

```
<ChartAreas>
     <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
         <AxisX>
              <MajorGrid LineWidth="0" />
         </AxisX>
     </asp:ChartArea>
</ChartAreas>
```